# Custom CheckBox with ListView

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have Implemented the custom check box with list view. I am getting the list now I want the list of package names which are checked with the help of getting position.How to get the position is there any way to do this.

```
class Custom_List extends BaseAdapter {

                Activity activity = null;
                List<String>  app_name = null;
                List<String>  app_usage = null;
                List<String>  app_last_updated = null;
                List<String>  app_cpu_usage = null;
                List<String>  app_package = null;

                public Custom_List(Activity this_activity, List<String> app_name2, List<String> app_usage, List<String> app_last_modi_data, List<String> app_CPU_Usage,List<String> app_package) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

                    activity = this_activity;
                    this.app_name = app_name2;
                    this.app_usage = app_usage;
                    this.app_last_updated = app_last_modi_data;
                    this.app_cpu_usage = app_CPU_Usage;
                    this.app_package=app_package;
                }

                public int getCount() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return app_name.size();
                }

                public Object getItem(int position) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return position;
                }

                public long getItemId(int position) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return position;
                }

                public  class ViewHolder {

                    public TextView textheader = null;
                    public TextView textcpu = null;
                    public TextView text_modified_date = null;
                    public TextView text_cpu = null;
                    public TextView text_checkbox = null;
                }

                ViewHolder holder = null;

                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    View vi = convertView;

                    if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some
                        // attributes
                        LayoutInflater  inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
                        holder = new ViewHolder();

                        holder.textheader = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.item1);
                        holder.textcpu = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.item2);
                        holder.text_modified_date = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.item4);
                        holder.text_cpu = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.item3);
                        holder.text_checkbox=(CheckBox)vi.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
                        vi.setTag(holder);

                    } else {
                        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();


                    }

                    holder.text_checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {


                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "coming here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            String packag=app_package.toString();
                            Log.d("package listttttttttt", packag);
                            addListenerOnButton() ;

                        }
                    });


                    holder.textheader.setText(Html.fromHtml(app_name.get(position)).toString());

                    int usage=Integer.parseInt(app_usage.get(position).toString().trim())/10000;

                    holder.textcpu.setText("Mem: "+String.valueOf(usage)+" M");

        //          System.out.println("      app_last_updated       "+app_last_updated.get(position).toString().trim());

                    holder.text_modified_date.setText("Last Updated Date: "+app_last_updated.get(position).toString().trim());
                    holder.text_cpu.setText("CPU: "+app_cpu_usage.get(position).toString().trim()+" %");
                    return vi;
                }

            }   
            private void addListenerOnButton() {
                Clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
                Clear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "coming in button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                });

            }
        }
```